# How I can upload LZMA file format to AWS?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, put, lzma

I want to upload a file that **LZMA** Format(unity asset bundle) to Amazon server using **PUT** method but I always get an error said:
"**errorMessage**": "Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object".
I try to buffer the file but it is not working so what is the best way to upload this type of file.

```
                    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
                    var s3 = new aws.S3();
                    var mime = require('mime-types');
                    //.....
                    var mimetype = mime.lookup(f.name);
                    if (mimetype == false) {
                        mimetype = 'application/octet-stream';
                    }
                  //is not working 
                  //  var buffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array (f));
                  // fs.readFile(f, function (err, data)
                  s3.putObject({
                            Bucket: "my backet",
                            Key: f.name,
                            Body: f,
                            ContentType: mimetype,
                            CacheControl: 'no-cache',
                            Expires: 0
                        }, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                context.fail(err, "error");
                            }
                            console.log("success:" + f.name);
                        });
```

Comment: What exactly is `f`?

Comment: its file LZMA Format contains 3D models.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/AssetBundleCompression.html

Comment: Put usually works with a byte-stream. Did you try instead of using a buffer to hand it the complete `byte[]` ?

Comment: I didn't try it before can you give me an example tutorial.